# Does redshift is supported by .net core framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-redshift

Is redshift being supported by .net core framework? Please provide a sample code for this if it does. Redshift does support .net framework with the ODBC but looking for .net core references.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Redshift can be [accessed via ODBC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-odbc-connection.html).

Alternatively, you can use the AWS SDK for .Net to access the [Amazon Redshift Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/RedshiftDataAPIService/TRedshiftDataAPIServiceClient.html) to directly query Redshift without using ODBC.